# Transform scale() Safari bug when used on elements with border

Tags: html, css, safari

CSS transform scale() function appears to have a bug on Safari when it's used on elements with a border.

I'm trying to zoom an image on mouse over using transform: scale() function but if the image has a border then it gets pixelated when scaled.
Here is a sample of the same element with the same CSS rules applied (except the border):
[image]

Code example: https://jsfiddle.net/m6g4kw30/

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 20px;
}

img.noborder {
  border: none;
}

img:hover {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(5);
  -moz-transform: scale(5);
  -ms-transform: scale(5);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0) scale(5);
  transform: translateZ(0) scale(5);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000.png" alt="">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000.png" class="noborder" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried with a shadow instead border `box-shadow:0 0 0 1px black` or a padding + a background `padding:1px;background-black` to check out if a bug also appears ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @G-Cyr. I've tried it with box-shadow but the same bug occurs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> CSS transform scale() function appears to have a bug on Safari when it's used on elements with a border.

You can say that again! Unfortunately, the reported bug(s) for this (and similar) issues go back **many** years, with the following bug referenced in most:

- https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=27684 (Opened in 07/2009)

If you didn't catch the date, **it's a 10 year old bug** that's still causing developers issues today! *YIKES*.

Basically, the issue comes down to Safari rasterizing the layer. On `transform/scale`, it resizes the layer, however it does not re-render the rasterized layer. In your use-case, the rasterized image is scaled up, but the text/image is blurry.

As for a workaround/fix? There are a couple ways you can "address" this:

**1) Force a re-render**

A quick/easy fix is to force Safari to re-render your layer when you transform. One way this can be achieved is by applying a CSS property which you then change after transforming (some people have success changing a background-color, for example). For your specific use case, I had luck with the following combination:

```
img {
    outline: 1px solid #000;
    border: none;
}

img:hover {
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

By toggling those specific values, I was able to force Safari to re-render the rasterized layer, thus rendering a sharp image (similar to the non-border example). Here's a JSFiddle with the full code example: https://jsfiddle.net/gc56brfh/

**2) Scale down, then up**

Another workaround, documented [here](https://codepen.io/blucube/pen/eDBdg), is to set the element's initial size to the "scaled up" dimensions, and then scale down the element until you're ready to scale it up. That way, the element is rasterized to the correct dimensions.

CSS wise, that may look like:

```
img {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(0.2);
    height: 250px;
}

img:hover {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1);
}
```

In the above, we've set the `initial` size of the `img` to `250px` (this is based on your original css, with images being `50px` and then scaled up `5`). We then scale down the image by `0.2`, resulting in `50px`. On hover, we then scale back up to `250px` by setting `scale(1)`.

Here's an updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/df2zqgnx/

One thing to note is that other CSS properties might need to be updated with this workaround. For example, you'll notice in the fiddle I also needed to update the `border` from `1px` to `5px` to compensate for the scaling down.

Anyway, hope this was helpful and one of the solutions works for you!