# css translateZ makes elements blurry

Tags: css, cross-browser, translate3d

Here's a reproduction of my issue (codepen because apparently stackoverflow's iframe affects the rendering somehow):

https://codepen.io/Ironimus/pen/GRjxpXZ

When using `transform: translateZ` and `perspective` inner elements' edges and text become blurry. It works very differently in different browsers, too. In case it also depends on screen or OS, here are a few screenshots with descriptions:

In Google Chrome `transform: scale(2)` is fine. Text and inner elements become blurry depending on the width of the element with `perspective`, and it follows very strange logic, when I set the `width` to 847px or higher it breaks, lower looks ok:
[image: Rendering issues in Google Chrome, 50vw width and 1000px width makes elements blurry, others are fine]

In Mozilla Firefox text becomes blurry if `perspective`/`translateZ` combination is used, inner elements are fine, `transform: scale(2)` is ok as well. `width` doesn't seem to affect anything:
[image: Rendering issues in Mozilla Firefox, all elements with translateZ and perspective are blurry, transform: scale looks fine]

In Safari everything is hella blurry whatever I do:
[image: Rendering issues in Safari, everything is blurry]

Why is it blurry at all and how do I make it right? Using `transform: scale(2)` for everything isn't a viable option. Are there maybe some rules I should follow to help browsers render 3D transforms with text right?

Supporting Safari isn't a priority but would still be nice

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding a custom -webkit to the browser?

Comment: doesn't seem to affect anything in any browser

Comment: Try to use the same measurement units when sizing the width and height values. Example `width: 50vh;` and `height: 5vh;`

Comment: in the codepen above there is one example that uses pixels for width and height. Still doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

I am probably late with this answer but I recently encountered the same behavior when implementing a parallax design for a website.
This is a problem related to text being rendered as bitmaps in Safari, which are not re-rendered on transform: scale(x); but instead blown up in size.
It is possible to manually trigger a re-render of the text in some cases, however this is very finicky and there's no guaranteed way to make it work.
A more comprehensive answer to this was provided by Jack in this thread:
[Transform scale() Safari bug when used on elements with border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55912280/transform-scale-safari-bug-when-used-on-elements-with-border/55916005#55916005)

Comment: Just realised I accidentally removed codepen a few days ego, edited my post with the new link. The problem wasn't with scale but with 3d transforms. I still haven't found a good solution. In my real use case it is supposed to become bigger/smaller dynamically. When I made everything bigger by default and scaled it down I got the opposite problem, antialiasing didn't work, also very visible on elements with contrasting borders: https://codepen.io/Ironimus/pen/ZELQQzE, and screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/2T7IXbK. I think I'll just rewrite the 3d part to three js